# after_commit is never being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am on rails 4.2.10. I need to trigger a job using sidekiq in after_save method. But the job is triggered, before the object is committed into the database, so I get the error, object  not found with id=xyz.

So, I need to use

`after_commit :method_name, :on => [:create, :update]`

But the changes that I made in object doesn't show up in above method. I have an attribute `email`. When I was calling above method `after_save`, `email_changed?` return `true`. But if I call the same method using `after_commit`, `email_changed?` returns `false.

Is it because I am using `object.save` method and not `create` method?

Below is the method, which I am calling to trigger the job:

```
def update_or_create_user
    if email_changed?
      ServiceUpdateDataJob.perform_later action: 'update', data: {type: 'user', user_id: self.id}
    end
    true
end
```

Comment: try to debug it , in your method, try to put `exit` for check whether it is going on method or not

Comment: it is not going inside, I have tried debugging using all the options.

Comment: sorry, `on_commit` is being called, but the changes that I made in the object aren't update. So, properties_chenged? filter failed.

Comment: can you provide method of `after_commit` ?

Comment: Can you just triggered the job after commit saved successfully ?

Comment: I added the method in the updated question. Please see above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164829/discussion-between-vishal-and-mukarram-ali).

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I solved this. I used a flag, set it `after_save` method to true, and in `after_commit`, I checked if the above flag is true then trigger the job.

Comment: Good, glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this isn't exactly an answer to your question as stated. However...

IMO, you're overloading your model's responsibilities. I suggest you create a service that triggers the job when your model is saved. It might look something like:

```
class FooService

  attr_accessor :unsaved_record

  class << self

    def call(unsaved_record)
      new(unsaved_record).call
    end

  end

    def initialize(unsaved_record)
      @unsaved_record = unsaved_record
    end

    def call
      kick_off_job if unsaved_record.save
      !unsaved_record.new_record?
    end

  private

    def kick_off_job
      # job logic
    end  

end
```

You might use the service in a controller something like:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController 

  def create
    @new_record = ModelName.new(record_params)
    if FooService.call(@new_record)
      # do successful save stuff
    else
      # do unsuccessful save stuff 
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: And to me, this makes the code more complex. I'll prefer the formal way.